# Numpy unpack binary string into a single variable

Tags: python, numpy, binary, packing

In Numpy, I need to unpack some binary data into a single variable. In the past I've been unpacking it using the 'fromstring' function in Numpy and extracting the first element. Is there a way I can unpack binary data into a Numpy type directly and avoid the overhead of creating a Numpy array that I pretty much ignore?

This is currently what I do:

```
>>> int_type
dtype('uint32')
>>> bin_data = '\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d'
>>> value = numpy.fromstring(bin_data, dtype = int_type)[0]
>>> print type(value), value
<type 'numpy.uint32'> 1295788826
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
>>> value = int_type.fromstring(bin_data)
>>> print type(value), value
<type 'numpy.uint32'> 1295788826
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [16]: import struct

In [17]: bin_data = '\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d'

In [18]: value, = struct.unpack('<I', bin_data)

In [19]: value
Out[19]: 1295788826
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> np.frombuffer(bin_data, dtype=np.uint32)
array([1295788826], dtype=uint32)
```

While this creates an array structure, the actual data is shared between the string and the array:

```
>>> x = np.frombuffer(bin_data, dtype=np.uint32)
>>> x[0] = 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: array is not writeable
```

whereas `fromstring` would copy it.